# Insert a value in 2dim vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I copied a 2dim array into a vector as below

```
vector< vector<int>> path2;
 vector<int> temp; // For simplicity
 for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
{temp.clear();
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        temp.push_back(path1[x][y]);
    }
    path2.push_back(temp);

}
```

now I want to inser a value in its second dimention how can I do it?(i know how to use an inser() in 1 dim vector)

for example

```
path2[0][6,0,2,6]
path2[1][6,1,3,6]
```

now how can I insert 4 between 1 and 3 ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [***`std::vector::insert`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

`path2[1].insert( path2[1].begin()+2, 4 );`